# Geração de ID único com MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Estou utilizando o código abaixo para testes com um sistema de login em PHP e MySQL. Porém o campo `nivel_usuario` gera um número de 0 à 2, e eu gostaria que gerasse um ID único com 6 dígitos, contendo números e letras (tanto maiúsculas quanto minúsculas)

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios(
    usuario_id int(5) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    nome varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
    sobrenome varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
    email varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
    usuario varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
    senha varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
    info text NOT NULL,
    nivel_usuario enum('0','1','2') NOT NULL default '0',
    data_cadastro datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    data_ultimo_login datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    ativado enum('0','1') NOT NULL default '0',
    PRIMARY KEY  (usuario_id)
) ENGINE = MYISAM CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci COMMENT = '';
```

Comment: Bastaria mostrar o campo usuario_id em alguma base com os caracteres desejados (por exemplo, base 36 ou 64). Provavelmente qualquer solução que fuja disso é duvidosa, pois o fato de usar um conjunto de caracteres diferente de apenas números é mera formatação. Caso precise de pseudoaleatoriedade (o que também precisa ver se realmente é necessário) poderia usar um fator multiplicador baseado num número primo, por exemplo. Mas precisa ver se realmente precisa disso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poderia fazer isso :

```
$aleatorio = rand(6,6); // 6 CARACTERES
$valor = substr(str_shuffle("AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnPpQqRrSsTtUuVvYyXxWwZz0123456789"), 0, $aleatorio);
```

Em seguida verificar se o valor já existe na base de dados, senão utiliza o valor como chave no banco e se sim gera outro hash.

Todas as respostas são válidas e boas, no entanto respondi seguindo a pergunta do colega, ele quer com seis dígitos, letras maiúsculas e minúsculas. Minha resposta está correta porque faz o que foi solicitado conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: Imagem do script executado]

Portanto não entendo porque a pontuação negativa sobre a resposta.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar os métodos de geração de identificadores únicos baseados no `timestamp`, são eles:

`PHP` [`uniqid()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php):

```
printf("uniqid(): %s", substr(uniqid(), -6));
```

`MySQL` [`UUID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid):

```
SELECT LEFT(uuid(), 6);
```

Como você quer apenas `6` dígitos, as funções [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) e [`LEFT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_left) foram utilizadas para auxiliar no tratamento da `string` obtendo a quantidade de caracteres desejados.

Comment: Sua resposta é boa inicialmente tinha pensado sobre uniqid() também, no entanto não devolve letras maiúsculas e minúsculas conforme estipulado em pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer que seja único atribua o `UNIQUE` na coluna, isso irá prevenir duplicações, o próprio MySQL irá impedir a inserção de dois valores iguais:

```
ALTER TABLE sua_tabela ADD UNIQUE (nome_da_coluna);
```

---

Para gerar tais dados aleatórios você poderia utilizar o `random_bytes`, ele é criptograficamente seguro.

Como você não deseja armazenar em bytes você pode usar a BASE64, que inclui `A-Za-z0-9+/` e possui um padding de `=`. <sub>*Lembrando que ele inclui o `/` e `+` além das letras e números.*</sub>

No final poderá usar:

```
$aleatorio = substr( base64_encode( random_bytes(4) ), 0, -2);
```

Isso vai gerar 4 bytes (ou seja 4294967296 possibilidades), resultando em 6 dígitos devido ao BASE64. O `substr` é usado para remover o `=`, desnecessário neste caso.

---

<sub><sub>*O `base64_encode` nativo não é em tempo-constante, se realmente se preocupa com isso [pode utilizar esta implementação](https://github.com/paragonie/constant_time_encoding/tree/aa342bff0f39b72da79b62b72d95a9bb86aa80b9).*</sub></sub>

Comment: Sua resposta me parece a melhor de todas +1