# Qual a melhor maneira para gerar um código aleatório que não se repita no banco de dados?

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso gerar um código aleatório de 5 caracteres, não podem ter repetições. Consegui fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
function testarcode($code){
    global $link;
    if ($code == ""){
        return false;
    }
    $comando = "SELECT * FROM tbl_usuario WHERE code='$code'";
    $query = mysqli_query($link, $comando);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}

function gerarcode(){
    $caracteres = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    $max = strlen($caracteres) - 1;
    $code = "";
    while (testarcode($code) == false){
        for($i=0; $i < 5; $i++) {
            $code .= $caracteres[mt_rand(0, $max)];
        }
    }
    return $code;
}
```

Apesar de estar funcionando eu achei meu código bem porco. Tem alguma maneira de faze-lo de forma mais fácil e/ou simplificada?

Não é uma duplicada de outras perguntas porque nessa pergunta é pedido um código em `PHP` e em outras, em `MySql`.

Comment: maximo 5 caracteres?

Comment: Tem de ser 5 caracteres, sem mais, sem menos.

Comment: Já adicionei uma resposta.

Comment: Se que garantir que ele não se repita, primeiro defina um index de tipo `UNIQUE` no campo, em seguida para cada novo código gerado, faça uma consulta para ver se ele já existe, caso existe, gere um código de novo, caso contrário, grave no banco.

Comment: Não seria duplicada? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/222090/gera%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-id-%C3%BAnico-com-mysql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

você pode usar a [função uniqid](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.uniqid.php) que retorna um identificador único prefixado baseado no tempo atual em milionésimos de segundo.

```
echo uniqid();
// Saida: 5975b4239b793
```

ou também pode passar um parametro para a função `uniqid`, por exemplo:

```
echo uniqid(rand());
// Saida: 103550780059754516d29da
```

Para pegar os 5 primeiros caracteres use a [função sbstr()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php)

```
echo substr(uniqid(rand()), 0, 5);
// Saida: 43395
```

Comment: Desconhecia dessa função `uniqid()`, obrigado!

Comment: Boa resposta, apenas recomendo verificar se não está repetido no banco de dados antes de inserir os dados, pois seu limite máximo de combinações vai ser 376.992 devido a sua limitação de 5 caracteres, bem menos que o próprio uniqueid() pode fornecer (5.3 undecilions)